# Mangled XML input for WebService

Tags: xml, input, character-encoding

I have a webservice, which supposedly accepts:

```
<tag1>&lt;datadatdata></tag1>
```

Can an XML parser survive unexpected `>`?

I am asking for a Java environment on client side, I don't know what runs on server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to the less-than char `<` which **must be escaped** as `&lt;`, the greater than char `>` can be used right away in an element or an attribute value and **can optionally be escaped** as `&gt;`.

This is explained [here at Liquid Technologies](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/XML/EscapingData.aspx):

Element Data

> The '<' character must be escaped within element text data so it is not confused for the opening brace of the next element.
>   The '&' character must always be escaped.
>   The other replacements (even the closing brace '>') are optional, but its good practice to always escape them.

Comment: hmmm.. don't understand.. first you say no, than the yellow text says > is optional..

Comment: I hope that I clarified my answer. `>` can be used, an escaping as `&gt;` is optional.

Comment: I'm glad that this solves your problem. The reason for this could become clear if you'd try to write an XML parser.

Comment: The statement that `>` "must not be escaped as &gt;" is false. It can optionally be escaped as `&gt;`.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Thanks. I fixed the wrong formulation. I was lost in translation.